# How to overwrite a field of the Super object in the child class in Java?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have these two classes:

```
class Parent
{ 
   protected static String table;

   public static long getRow()
   {
      String query = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE id =? " ;
      //other code...
   }
}
```

I then extend this class :

```
class Child extends Parent
{
    protected static String table = "tableName";
   //other code..
}
```

However, when I try to do this:

`long id = Child.getRow();`

I get an error, because the query is getting "null" put in it where the value of `table` should be. I.e `SELECT * FROM null`.

I thought that setting the value of `table` in the child class would cause it to be updated in the methods it inherits as well, but apparently not. What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot override variables this way. In your example, each class has its own version of the `table` variable, and in the Parent, where the `getRow` method is defined, the variable is undefined. Here's a better design you can use:

```
abstract class Parent {

   public abstract String getTable();

   public static long getRow() {
      String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE id = ?", getTable()) ;
      //other code...
   }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public String getTable() {
        return "tableName";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I make `getTable()` be static while being abstract?

Comment: @ClickUpvote - no you cannot. It wouldn't make sense since static methods are bound to the class in which they are declared, but abstract methods defer implementation to other classes.

Answer (score 1):

**instance variables**(also static variables) are `not overridden in your subclass`. they are only visible in your subclass if they are marked as protected, public or default. polymorphism and inheritence doesn't apply to instance variable. for your code to work the only option is to make your getRow() method public override it in your subclass

Answer (score 0):

Replace the naked field access with a getter/setter method.

When you override the getter/setter in the subclass, then you are given control over what variable it reads to and writes.

Java does not provide this level of control over field access.

Answer (score 0):

Just one little thing. Inside a method you can access an shadowed field with super. If you place this code in the Child class:

```
public void foo() {

    this.table="this belongs to the child";
    super.table="this belongs to the parent";
}
```

note that this.table and super.table are different. Anyway shadowing fields are not advised.